# show lyrics on ubuntu

Tags: python, plugins, gnome, rhythmbox

I'm writing a little script for Ubuntu. 
My intention is to call rhythmbox lyrics plug-in with a global short-cut (configuring gnome)  .
I can call it from rhythmbox python console, but I don't know how to import rhythmbox built-in modules (eg. rhythmdb).
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can't import rhythmbox "built-in" modules from a standard python console.

As far as I know they aren't real modules, they are just objects from the rhythmbox process exposed to plugins. So you can access them only if you are running your script from the rhythmbox process.

Answer (score 0):

in this case i guess you'll have to write the whole plugin yourself and , then listen to dbus for change of songs in rhythmbox , to detect which song is being played .